# Laravel hide or remove some database column data from result

Tags: php, laravel

in Laravel `API` i have some method which they are return some fields which i don't want to have in result, for example:

```
id  -  email  -  user_id
```

and they are optional and i can't set this fields into self models, now i'm using this class as `ManageResource` to `hode/remove` fields/columns from result like this code:

```
$user = User::whereApiToken($request->api_token)->first();
$result = ManageResource::make($user)->hide(['id','email']);
```

after using this code that implemented by below class i get only `id` and `email` on array keys, but i want to hide them

`ManageResource` class:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ManageResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $withoutFields = [];

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->filterFields($this->withoutFields);
    }

    /**
     * Set the keys that are supposed to be filtered out.
     *
     * @param array $fields
     * @return $this
     */
    public function hide(array $fields)
    {
        $this->withoutFields = $fields;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the filtered keys.
     *
     * @param $array
     * @return array
     */
    protected function filterFields($array)
    {
        return collect($array)->toArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

As you would like to make some typically visible attributes hidden on a **given model instance**, you may use the makeHidden method.

```
return $user->makeHidden('attribute')->toArray();
```

Here, `$user` represents user model

**Example Case :** use makeHidden with code to hide column in pagination result

```
$result = Job::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->paginate(5);
$data =$result;
$result= $result->makeHidden(['hasMessage']);
$data->data = $result;
return $data;
```

**In Your case :**

```
$result = ManageResource::make($user)->makeHidden(['id','email'])->toArray();
$data->data = $result;
return $data;
```

or

```
$result = User::whereApiToken($request->api_token)->first()->setHidden(['id', 'email']);
$data->data = $result;
return $data;
```

**Note :**

As far as I'm aware, makeHidden doesn't affect relations. It would have been good if it allowed you to specify attributes in relations as -makeHidden(['relation.field']). Alternatively you can use following code

```
App\Models\Product::with(['images' => function ($query) {             
 $query->select(['id','product_id','image_url',   
'row_id'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');                            
}])->get()->makeHidden(['id']);
```

**In your case**

```
$tickets = UserTickets::with(['user', 'reply' => function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->with('user')->select(['id','Attrib1','Attrib2'])->whereUserId($user->id);
}])->whereTicketNumber($request->ticket_number)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, how about this link: `https://stackoverflow.com/q/51131225/1830228` could you help me?

Comment: You're welcome. Its page not found for this link. Seems you found the solution, isn't it ?

Comment: how can i user your code to nested data? for exameple nested data inside array

Comment: As per laravel documentation, makeHidden() function is to hide attributes on a given model means you'll not get unnecessary data into data set.

Comment: Please share that code lines which returns that nested array as response

Comment: I'm sorry unfortunately as far `->setHidden` dont work on collection or array, i'm trying to fix my code that i pasted on post

Comment: App\Models\Product::with(['images' => function ($query) {                                                                                                                                              $query->select(['id','product_id','image_url', 'row_id'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');                                                                                                          }])->get()->makeHidden(['id']);

Comment: Sorry to late reply was little busy. agree ->setHidden doesn't work on relation but we can tweak it through ->select() in relation query, there pass only the fields you look to fetch from relation table, check my updated comment for more details..I have tested it at my side..it works

Comment: Thanks a lot, please let me to test that

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, +1  @Amitesh

Answer (score 1):

You can use map filter to get the desired fields.

```
$events= Events::where(['id' => 1])->get()
            ->map(function ($event) {
                return [
                    'id' => $event->id,
                    'title' => $event->title,
                    'target' => $event->specific,
                    'date' => $event->start . '-' . $event->end,
                    'created' => $event->created_at
                ];
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the easiest way be to use the `setHidden()` method on the model itself?

```
$user = User::whereApiToken($request->api_token)->first()->setHidden(['id', 'email']);

echo $user;
```

Given the table/field structure `id  -  email  -  user_id` this should result in something like:

```
{"user_id": 1}
```

Comment: `->setHidden` only work on specific models, not on array or collection

Comment: I know. But your `ManageResource` class seemed unnecessary if it's only task was to remove specific fields from a model. Since you do `->first()` you'll only get a single model returned, which you can use `->setHidden()` on. So, the cleanest solution to your example I think.

Comment: some data output in my web application are not from single model, for the matter i would like to develop my own class and fix problems, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
User::select('name')->get();
User::select('name', 'email')->get();
User::all()->pluck('name'); // array
```

Comment: You can add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

you can use [get()](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Resources/ConditionallyLoadsAttributes.html#method_filter)

```
$result = new (ManageResource($user))->get(['name']);
```

it will return only the values that you want.

Comment: i get this error:  `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter does not exist.`

Comment: your code is not correct; that should be `(new UsersResource($user))->get(['id','name'])` and i want to hide not get specific columns

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['data'] = array();
   $rows= Product::with('category')->get()
        ->map(function ($rows) {
            array_push($_SESSION['data'],array(
                'id' => $rows->id,
                'title' => $rows->title,
                'price' => $rows->price,
                'photo' => $rows->price,
                'categorytitle' => $rows->category->title,
                'created_at' => $rows->getCreationDate(),
                'updated_at' => $rows->getUpdationDate(),

            ));
        });
   $data = $_SESSION['data'];
   unset($_SESSION['data']);
   return view("products")->with("result",$data);
```